# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una consulta que lleve esta condición?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito una consulta que me incluya todos aquellos clientes que por lo menos tengan en existencia 1 o más cantidad de producto si no es así que no me muestre nada de ese cliente.

Aquí les dejo una imagen de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, el cliente ***1200005*** no tiene en existencia zanahoria, entonces solo quiero que me muestre el cliente ***1200004***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo? porque lo que estas pidiendo parece ser un simple select con un where. tuviste alguna dificultad en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que pasa es que no se como formular la consulta ya que soy nuevo en esto :s

Comment: Podrias mencionar el motor de base de datos SQL SERVER,MYSQL ORACLE, y las estructuras de tus tablas

Comment: `SELECT id_cliente, producto, existencia, inventario FROM nombre_de_la_tabla WHERE existencia > 0` Obviamente reemplaza nombre_de_la_tabla con el nombre respectivo.

Comment: @aeportugal pero si realizo esa consulta también me va a mostrar las existencias del cliente 1200005 y lo que yo quiero es que si al menos no tiene una existencia en algún producto solo muestre los que tengan todos los productos, como el ejemplo que puse del cliente 1200004

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Utilizo SQL SERVER y la estrucura la puse en las imagenes

Comment: No te preocupes Carlos, todos empezamos alguna vez. Ordenemos tu pregunta. Lee los enlaces que te pase. Cual es tu resultado esperado? que intentaste? cual es el resultado que te salio? todo eso, tiene que estar en la pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] y agrega lo que falte. Tene en cuenta que tenemos que entenderte para poder contestarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectifico mi comentario, el 4to, ya que no entendí bien la pregunta.
Hice una prueba con SQLServer 2005, que es el que tengo a mano, pero que probablemente funcione en cualquier versión de servidor.

```
SELECT id_cliente, producto, existencia, inventario 
FROM nombre_de_tabla
WHERE id_cliente NOT IN (SELECT id_cliente FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE existencia = 0)
```

En el `WHERE` se hace una comparación del `id_cliente` contra otro `SELECT` que va a devolver el mismo `id_cliente` solo si algún valor de `existencia` es 0. Cuando eso ocurra, la condición no se va a cumplir y entonces primer `SELECT` no va a devolver registros.

Comment: muchas Gracias es lo que buscaba  :D